# Why should I implement authentication challenges instead of passing basic authentication header right from the start?

Tags: http, authentication, https

I hope this question does not make me look dumb. But what are the benefits of making my native app (example iOS swift app) to respond to server authentication challenges instead of passing the authentication header
`Authentication: BASIC UserAndPasswordInBase64` right from the start?

This is of course assuming I have required credentials.

What is the logic for doing an extra request?

**For example**, Lets say I save the username and password in a secure store (like KeyChain) after the first login. By doing do sending own crafted header will save me one request from the next time the same users start the application.

Obviously I am missing something because otherwise machinery for the challenge request wouldn't have been built. It is just I don't know what :(

Thanks in advance.